# What is the equivalent Atom Indent Guides like in Brackets?

Tags: html, css, editor, atom-editor, adobe-brackets

What is the equivalent Atom Indent Guides like the one Bracket has showing vertical lines connecting matching beginning/opening and ending/closing brackets or keywords?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Atom supports "Indent Guides" and even names it the same, you can access the configuration by choosing `Settings View: Open` from the [Command Palette](https://atom.io/packages/command-palette)
or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> (Control + Comma).  Scroll about two-thirds of the way down and there is a checkbox to toggle the Indent Guide on or off:

[image: Screenshot of Indent Guides on in Settings]

When enabled they look like this in the editor:

[image: Screenshot of Indent Guides]

Answer (score 2):

Also found an "improved" package in Atom if Atom's indent-guide isn't cutting it.

https://atom.io/packages/indent-guide-improved

Repo seems to be updated.

Comment: i like how this highlights the line corresponding to the current mouse cursor scope

Comment: how do you install this package? It wasn't very clear to me on the page and I'm new to the atom editor.

Comment: @JosephAstrahan On mac (assuming windows has something similar): open atom --> click atom dropdown --> preferences --> click install tab --> in search packages input, type "indent-guide-improved" press enter --> find the indent-guide-improved package and click install.   if you have apm cli installed, go to your command line and type "apm install indent-guide-improved"

Comment: Thanks so much :), this really helped.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: `show indent guide` option is now under `Editor` tab, in settings.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Consider updating an existing answer instead of submitting a new one, especially when another answer offers further explanation already.

Answer (score 0):

Haha. I encountered this issue today too. If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how to enable this feature?

Go to preferences/settings and then scroll down and check 'show indent guide'.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ4Vg.png)